# Questions on Chinese Encoding

Tags: browser, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I'm trying to create a webpage in Chinese and I realized that while the text looks fine when I run it on browsers, once I change the Character Encoding, the text becomes gibberish. Here's what's happening:

1. I create my html file in Emacs, encoded in UTF-8.
2. I upload it to the server, and view it on my browsers (FF, IE, Chrome, Opera) - no problem.
3. I try to view the page in other encodings via FF > View > Character Encoding > All those different Chinese encoding systems, e.g. Chinese Simplified (HZ)
4. Apart from UTF-8, on every other encoding the text becomes gibberish.

I'm assuming this isn't a problem - i.e. browsers are smart enough to know which encoding the page is in, and parse the content accurately. What I'm wondering is why I can't read the Chinese text anymore once I change encoding - is it because I don't have Chinese fonts installed on my OS? Should I stick to UTF-8 if my audience are Chinese or should I choose among one of their many encoding systems?

Thanks in advance for your help/opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF isn't a 'catch-all' encoding. It's designed to contain international language character symbols for ease of use, but *it is still an encoding*, just like the other encodings you've selected. You would have to retype the text in each encoding to make it appear correctly when viewed with that encoding.

Comment: Retype the text? Are you saying that I should create separate files, each written and saved with a different encoding? Then how do I decide which file to serve?

Comment: Yes - but you should follow Agent_L's advice and define the charset encoding in the HTML, that will save far more time. If you want separate files, it should be possible to write a script to automatically encode UTF-8 to every other encoding that needs to be supported, but thinking forward, having multiple copies of the same content may become a maintenance hassle.

Comment: I believe that he meant a situation when client requests a file and explicitly demands it in some other encoding. While possible, it's quite unlikely for a modern browser to not support utf-8 (to my eu/us-biased knowledge).

Comment: Thanks guys for your contributions. Can I now say that it might be a better idea to have one encoding instead of many (say in UTF-8) and explicitly define the encoding in the html as well as on the server end? Coz' I've visited many huge Chinese sites (e.g. Yahoo! China) and again, if you change the encoding to something it doesn't support, the content becomes gibberish. I'm assuming the hassle of maintaining content in multiple encoding is just not worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, maintaining one file is almost always simpler than multiple files.

Comment: Ok noted. Thanks for your help, MHTri.

Answer (score 2):

Viewer encoding MUST match the file being read. Viewing UTF-8 as something other makes about same sense as renaming .txt to .exe and trying to run it.

You should specify correct encoding in HTML. The option you're using in web browser exist only for those rare occasions when web developer screwed up his job and declared other encoding than actually used OR mixed up 2 different encodings on one page.

Comment: Yeah I figured so too, because I've never had any problem viewing my pages - presume the browser detected the encoding for me. By the way, by "You should specify correct encoding in HTML", you mean `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` right?

Comment: Yes, or <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> for HTML older than 5. In case of problems, keep in mind that the server also declares the encoding when sending, in HTTP header. Admin of your server should know how to fix this one - IF it's broken. You can check these out in eg. Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Of course changing the encoding in your browser will "break" the text! The browser is taking the stream of UTF-8 codepoints and tries to force another encoding on the raw data. Needless to say, the result ain't pretty. Changing the encoding in the browser is NOT the equivalent of converting.

As you surmised correctly, modern browsers usually guess correctly -- but not always. As Agent_L make sure to declare the encoding in the headers.